# How to immediately remove from memory a value that has just been removed from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a java program, in which some data is added to an arraylist.

Some of the processing is within a loop, and I am adding a new node to the list within the loop, performing operations using that node, and then deleting that node using arraylist.remove() just before end of an iteration of the loop. I am also running System.gc(); just before end of a loop iteration.

However when I took a memory dump, I found that the arraylist still held all values that I had used in different loop iterations... How do I erase all of those values from memory? And I want to do this just before the end of an iteration of loop, so that the arraylist never grows in size?

Comment: Why are you concerned? Using a memory managed language like Java is supposed to hide these details from you.

Comment: the program which I am working on will be used to fetch millions of records, and at the rate at which memory is being used up, there is no way I can fetch all the data in one (or even few) runs of the program, without using up the entire memory of my machine...

Comment: why don't you use an array if you want a fixed size?

Comment: Attach jvisualvm in the JDK to your program and investigate memory usage as your program runs.

Comment: you don't know till you profile it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java have garbage collector for a reason, and that reason is to programmer don't have to think about removing object from memory. Only thing you can do (I don't recommend it) is to force start garbage collector by `System.gc()` method. But remember to do it twice because 1st time it will only prepare object to be removed by invoking it `finalize()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a memory dump of "live" objects, it will be removed.

The cost of removing objects is relatively high, so its usually best for performance in Java to only remove objects when you need to (when the JVM does it)

Comment: is there no way of removing objects from memory, with the help of a java command? that is what i am looking for...

Comment: I think you can call the garbage collector/

Comment: You have to ask yourself why you want to. The problem is that 99.9% of the time you don't care.  That is why you are using managed memory. BTW: Most of the memory I use is not managed but its VERY rare that you need to do this.

Comment: I use memory mapped files for dealing with large amounts of memory.  This allows me to use as much "memory" as I have disk space. Its more work to use, but can be worth it.  I have a dataset which is about 500 GB so I can't load it into memory without memory mapped files.

Comment: @Arvind: you almost certainly _don't_ need to do this.  The Java garbage collector is almost always smarter than you.  Trust it to do its job.  (In any event, there is literally _no way_ to force an object in Java to be removed from memory, so you don't have much choice.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to free part of the memory taken up by the ArrayList, rather than to free up the objects that were formerly stored in the ArrayList?  If so, you can do that by calling `ArrayList.trimToSize()` - that will copy all of the values in the ArrayList into a new (internal) array, and allow the old (internal) array to be garbage collected.  (Since that involves copying all of the values in the array, it should naturally only be done when it will make a big difference.)